# Relations between functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \to B ,~h: A \to B,~g: B \to A,~\ell: B \to A$.

$ \ell \circ h = g \circ h = g \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_A $

From here can I show that $\ell \circ f =\operatorname{Id}_A $? Here $\operatorname{Id}_A$ is the identity function sending $A$ to itself.

I cannot think of any counterexamples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible counterexample:

Let $A$ and $B$ be the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and let

- $f(a) = 2a$
- $h(a) = 2a+1$
- $g(b) = \lfloor b/2 \rfloor$
- $\ell (b) = \lfloor (b-1)/2 \rfloor$

then

- $g(f(a))=  \lfloor 2a/2 \rfloor = a$
- $g(h(a))=  \lfloor (2a+1)/2 \rfloor = a$
- $\ell(h(a))=  \lfloor ((2a+1)-1)/2 \rfloor = a$
- $\ell(f(a))=  \lfloor (2a-1)/2 \rfloor = a-1 \not =a$

So in this case $l \circ f\not = \operatorname{Id}_A$ even though $\ell \circ h = g \circ h = g \circ f = \operatorname{Id}_A$.